# How to only have the first thread lock a std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am new to C++11 threading.

The following piece of code should be executed only by the first thread.

The other threads (which might race with the first thread) should not enter the locked code area (that's why the `std::try_lock()` is there).

```
std::mutex mu;

// now ensure this will get called only once per event
if (std::try_lock(mu) != -1)
{ 
    return;
}

{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mu);
    // critical section

} // mutex will be unlocked here
```

(Outside from writing my own lock_guard) Is there a way to use a similar & standard `std::lock_guard` variant, but which will take my !locked! mutex (effect of `std::try_lock()` above) and simply unlock it when the d-tor of that guard will be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have a look at this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard)

[and this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag)

From this info you can see that if you specify a second parameter like this `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mutex, std::try_to_lock)` the behaviour is changed to act like `std::try_lock` rather than `std::lock`

Comment: Almost correct. lock_guard doesn't take a try_to_lock_t. It is however possible to use the existing try_lock in the ops code and then construct a lock_guard using std::adopt_lock to tell it that the mutex is already locked.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
// now ensure this will get called only once per event
if (_mutex.try_lock())
{ 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_mutex, std::adopt_lock);

    // critical section
} // mutex will be unlocked here
```

**Update** And don't use variable names starting with underscore (as `_mutex`).

Comment: Why not `use variable names starting with underscore`? [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)