# Use std::lock_guard with try_lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Is there a way I can tell `std::lock_guard` to call `try_lock` instead of `lock` when it acquires the mutex?

The only way I could think of is to use `std::adopt_lock`:

```
if (!_mutex.try_lock())
{
    // Handle failure and return from the function
}
std::lock_guard<my_mutex_class> lock(_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
```

Is there a built-in solution for my problem rather then acquiring the lock explicitly and then give `lock_guard` the responsibility for releasing it?

Answer (score 83):

A basic design invariant of `lock_guard` is that it always holds the lock. This minimizes the overhead since its destructor can unconditionally call `unlock()`, and it doesn't have to store extra state.

If you need the try-to-lock behavior, use `unique_lock`:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex, std::try_to_lock);
if(!lock.owns_lock()){
    // mutex wasn't locked. Handle it.
}
```

Comment: You can use std::lock_guard as follows: `if (_mutex.try_lock())
{ 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
}
`
(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30457040)

Comment: @iliis you mean, exactly what the question is trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes, yes exactly. I should read the questions as well, not just the answers... *facepalm*

Comment: I personally perfer `if(auto lock = std::unique_lock{_mutex, std::try_to_lock) { do_stuff(); }`

Comment: @BennoStraub the code you posted does not work, it should be:
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex, std::try_to_lock);
if (lock.owns_lock()) {}

Comment: @VincentRicosti It definitively works in C++11 and up. It inverts the logic though. You may also have to replace `std::unique_lock{ ... }` with `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(...)` in older C++ versions, because template parameter deduction and the curly brace stuff isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used to execute only if try_lock succeeds:

```
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    tryLockAndExecute(mutex,[this]()
    {
        // your code here
    });
}
```

Implementation:

```
void tryLockAndExecute(std::mutex& mutex, std::function<void()> execute)
{
    std::exception_ptr exceptionPtr;
    if (mutex.try_lock())
    {
        try
        {
            execute();
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            exceptionPtr = std::current_exception();
        }
        mutex.unlock();
        if (exceptionPtr)
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(exceptionPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer this to `unique_lock`?